# Firebase API - getting the gs url from an uploaded image

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I'm developing a React Native App using Expo and firebase. I'm Uploading a camera capture to firebase and then I need to get the google storage URL from Firebase back. I didn't understand how should I do this.
When I looked in my firebase storage I saw the URL I wanted but didn't understand how to get it back in react native code :

[image: capture from my firebase storage]

Comment: I think that might be a matter of calling `toString()` on the `StorageReference`. If that doesn't work, can you edit your question to show what you've tried?

Comment: Hello @Omar, is your issue resolved? If yes, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick icon so others know it has been answered or feel free to ask any queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Frank mentioned in the comments, you can just use `.toString()` on the storage reference like this:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var spaceRef = storageRef.child('/folder/image.png');
console.log(spaceRef.toString());
```

The Reference Object also has these properties:

`bucket`: <project-id>.appspot.com, `fullPath`: path to the object and `name`: name of the file/object

It also has the property `.parent` just in case you need to get some information from the parent directory.